# Load a Lazy Proxy Property

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I need to load a property on an object that is set for lazy load.  When I try to access it or load it using NhibernateUtil.Initialize(), I get the same error:

"Initializing[ProjectName.Logic.Entities.AddressList#9]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session."

I can ensure that the session DOES exist by calling the necessary method to open a session in the "using" clause.  (We have buried our session creation such that instantiating a repository object with a parameter of "true" will also create a session factory if needed and open a session.  Verified with a breakpoint triggered at the "using" clause.)

```
foreach (MemberViewModel MVM in _filteredMemberViewModels)
           {
               foreach (Detail Mailings in MVM.Member.Mailings)  
               {
                   //used for lazy loading
                   using (var repo = new AddressListRepository(true))
                   {
                       NHibernateUtil.Initialize(Mailings.AddressList);
                   }
               }
           }
```

Detail Mapping:

```
public class DetailMap : ClassMap<Detail>
{
    public DetailMap()
    {
        Table("AddressDetailsCCN");

        // Unique Identifier
        Id(x => x.Id, "Id")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();

        // MANY TO ONE relationship (the list has many details)
        References<AddressList>(x => x.AddressList, "ListId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.None();

        // MANY TO ONE relationship (Members have details)
        References<Member>(x => x.Member, "MemberId")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Not.Nullable();

        // First line of Address
        Map(x => x.Address, "Address")
            .Nullable();

        // Second line of Address
        Map(x => x.Address2, "Address2")
            .Nullable();

        // City
        Map(x => x.City, "City")
            .Nullable();

        // State
        Map(x => x.State, "State")
            .Nullable();

        // Zip
        Map(x => x.Zip, "Zip")
            .Nullable();

        // Finalized date
        Map(x => x.FinalizedDate, "FinalizedDate")
            .CustomType(typeof(DateTime))
            .Nullable();

        // Date the list is created by
        Map(x => x.CreatedDate, "CreatedDate")
            .CustomType(typeof(DateTime))
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the session is still open when you come to access the lazy loaded items? If you access the lazy loaded items after the end of the using statement, (i.e. in a consuming method) then the session may well already be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach your Mailings object to the session before you can initialize any properties on it.  You would have to expose a method on your repository to do so, which would call:

```
session.Lock(entity, LockMode.None);
```

That will then associate the entity (Mailings) with your session and then the call to NHibernateUtil.Initialize(Mailings.AddressList) should work.

However I would suggest re-considering why you need to do it this way and look at having coarser grained sessions (ie. open it earlier and close it later).